Import Chrome passwords to iCloud Passwords/Keychain without using a Mac (I have an iPhone)
I want to import Chrome passwords into iCloud Passwords/Keychain without using a Mac. I can't see an import CSV option anywhere in the app on iOS 18 on my iPhone.
Is there any way, potentially using some third party software, to get all the passwords into keychain?

I can’t think of a way to do this on iOS, but I did want to bring your attention to a windows extension you might leverage to transfer things from a PC to iCloud Keychain:

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/icloud-passwords/pejdijmoenmkgeppbflobdenhhabjlaj

There is an official iCloud passwords Windows app as well.
Borrowing (or owning) a Mac is the Apple designed way to import passwords from a CSV, but you’ve already rules that out in your requirements. Safari for macOS can import passwords (and other data) directly from other browsers, as the other import method Apple provides.
As of iOS 18.2 and iPadOS 18.2 direct import using the system settings, files app, or password app isn’t a feature that’s implemented.

I do have the extension and the Windows App already installed, but I cannot see any way to actually transfer passwords into the passwords app.
